# Matlab: If condition working on empty matrices, not working properly

Tags: matlab, if-statement

My variables and their values, in the `if` condition statement

```
leftoverROI1s{1}= [11 15];
```

`missinglabelsinimage{1}` is an empty matrix.

I want to execute a `for` loop only if both my conditions in the `if` statement are true, i.e.:

```
if ~isempty(leftoverROI1s{1}) && ~isempty(missinglabelsinimage{1})

    for % loop for each element in non-empty `missinglabelsinimage` structure array.
        % Add a scalar to each element of non-empty `missinglabelsinimage` structure array
        ...
    end % end for loop

end % end if
```

My program control is going into `for` loop (which I expect, it shouldn't if there is an empty `missinglabelsinimage{1})` and the control is working on `missinglabelsinimage{1}` (empty matrix), which obviously gives me an error as I am trying to add a scalar to my 'non-empty' `missinglabelsinimage{1}`.

I am not able to understand the error in my `if` condition. Any help would be appreciated.

PS: I checked the above variables

```
~isempty(missinglabelsinimage{1})
ans =    
     0

~isempty(leftoverROI1s{1})
ans = 
     1

missinglabelsinimage{1}
ans =
   Empty matrix: 1-by-0
```

Comment: I can't understand what you're asking. If `missinglabelsinimage{1}` is empty, and you say it is, then your `if` statement will prevent the `for` loop from executing, which seems to be exactly what you want.

Comment: Report the full error message and a reproducible example.

Comment: Write a function (not a script) which reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect there is a typo somewhere in code that you are not showing. Reducing your example to its most basic form (always a good idea to try to find a bug):

```
a = [];
b = [1 2 3];
display(~isempty(a))
display(~isempty(b))

if ~isempty(a) && ~isempty(b) 
    disp('we passed the if')
else
    disp('we are in the else')
end
```

Results in the output

```
ans =
     0
ans =
     1
we are in the else
```

Exactly as you would expect. If you get something different, then the code you are using isn't the code you are showing... is there a similar (mistyped) variable somewhere? Try doing a `clear all`, then run a minimal example that reproduces your problem.